# What Does OpenCL Upsample Do?

Tags: opencl

After reading the documentation for the OpenCL function `upsample`, I still have no idea what it does.

The documentation's description of the function is:

```
result[i] = ((gentype)hi[i] << 8|16|32) | lo[i]
```

What does that mean?  What does `upsample` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is best explained through code rather than words (a snippet is worth 2^10 words, after all):

```
uchar hi = 0xAA;
uchar lo = 0xBB;

ushort x = upsample(hi, lo); // x = 0xAABB
```

There are overloads for signed versions which respect the signedness rules, and vector overloads too:

```
uchar2 hi = (uchar2)(0xAA, 0xBB);
uchar2 lo = (uchar2)(0x11, 0x22);

ushort2 x = upsample(hi, lo); // x = {0xAA11, 0xBB22}
```

Those don't do anything special as you might conceivably imagine, they just operate component-wise.

---

Mathematically, the description of the function makes sense, by "pushing" the `hi` argument to the most significant bits of the output so that it appears in the first 8 (`short`), 16 (`int`), 32 (`long`) bits. Below is an example using the `ushort upsample(uchar hi, uchar lo)` overload for illustration:

```
upsample(hi, lo) = (hi << 8) | lo

hi = 01010101
lo = 01101110

lo      = 0000000001101110 (extended to result type ushort)
hi << 8 = 0101010100000000 (extended to result type ushort)

(hi << 8) | lo = 0101010100000000
               | 0000000001101110
               = 0101010101101110
                 ^       ^
                 hi      lo
```

---

Actually, thanks, I didn't know about this function, I could certainly make use of it myself. Cheers!

Comment: +1 There are similar cpu-avx/sse instructions which is documented like you did here.